# Почему регулярное выражение дает false?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$reg = '/(http|https)):\/\/(www\.)*youtube\.com\/.*/';

if(preg_match($reg, $url)){
        return true;
    }
return false;
```

Для ссылки `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vP1PeXHba64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лишняя закрывающая скобка после https

https://regex101.com/r/iR2pO8/1